# Apache2 404 page customisation to remove requested URL being printed

Tags: apache

There are two questions I need to ask here. The first of which is how to customise the default Apache 404 page. I'm running the same version of Apache (2.4.29) on separate environments, however the customisation of the 404 pages are different. On one environment, if I search for a non-existent page, I receive the following page:
[image]

If I search for the exact same URL (/%2f%20Please%20visit%20www.evil.com) on the other server, I receive this 404 page:
[image]

My question is, where can I change the 404 page so they're consistent?

I also have another question following this. If I'm using the ErrorDocument 404 directive in my site's .htaccess file to present a nicer 404 page, why wouldn't it work with the path /%2f%20Please%20visit%20www.evil.com ? It works for other paths that don't look like they're trying to exploit XSS.

Answer (score 0):

You either have a custom 404 page showing the link.

### OR

No, you are not using the same Apache version in both of those systems.

Older Apache versions show the URL in the page, but the newer ones do not.

It is in modules/http/http_protocol.c in the sources, you could go editing it if you want to use it in the newer versions.

It was changed in Apache 2.4.41.